# How can I calculate a time difference with JavaScript's float-only math?

Tags: javascript

**Goal:** Take a Unix-time value from the past, and express its offset from current time in the format "10h 18m 22s".

**Current Code:**

```
function humaniseTime(epoch) {
  nowtime = (new Date).getTime()/1000; // current ms to s
  secs = Math.round(nowtime-epoch);

  hours = secs/3600;
  secs -= hours*3600;

  minutes = secs/60;
  secs -= minutes*60;

  clockstring = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + secs + "s";
  return clockstring;
}
```

The problem is that because JavaScript isn't working with integers but with floats, I just wind up getting 0.564166666 hours rather than 0h 17m 22s. Using a rounding function gives me negative times which is no good.

Comment: How did you round that it gave you a negative time? Which rounding function did you use?

Comment: Please use [local variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)!

Answer (score 0):

I have written another solution for you which is different from yours but working like a charm, here is the code:

```
function secondsToString(seconds)
{
    var numyears = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
    var numdays = Math.floor((seconds % 31536000) / 86400); 
    var numhours = Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600);
    var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    var numseconds = (((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
    return numyears + " years " +  numdays + " days " + numhours + " hours " + numminutes + " minutes " + numseconds + " seconds";

}

var epoch = Math.floor(1294862756114/1000);  //in your case this will be function argument, converting it into seconds as well
alert("Epoch: " + epoch)
var time = Math.floor((new Date().getTime())/1000);
alert("Current Time: " + time);
var difference = time-epoch;
alert("Difference: " + secondsToString(difference));
```

It's fairly straight forward hopefully you won't have a problem understanding it. I have basically added a function which converts seconds to number of years, months, days, hours. You can play around with it now to keep whatever values you need.

**[See the deamo here](http://jsfiddle.net/x8bposjt/)**